# Trying to find stories that were published on Fatalistic.net or Fatalism.net

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find the series of original stories that were written on the web. The only titles I can remember are *The Ties that Bind* and *Borderline*. They were two female authors, whose names I have regrettably forgotten. I suppose the last time I read any of their works was in 2000? Their website had a black theme and a section for fan-art.
Main characters in the series are Asher, he has gold eyes and is an empath and his parents would lock him in a cupboard/closet. Aren and Peter.

There is also a story where four humans are chosen to be the four horsemen; one is given a sword, the other a white horse, etc. In the end, they committed group suicide by cutting their wrists so that they wouldn't use these gifts and destroy the world. They end up in heaven.

Another story has a group of friends who role-play a fantasy game and they end up in Hoka Sekai! In the end a friend from the real world is invited over into Hoka Sekai and he writes his name as Neb instead of Ben!

Truly a unique set of stories all found in the same place. Majority fantasy theme ranging from Angels and Demons to mutants, to alternate realities like Log Horizon. Only they created the game/world which became real. The website isn't there any more, I'd love to catch up with the authors who influenced a huge part of my high school years.

Comment: [This](http://web.archive.org/web/20160315000000*/http://Fatalistic.net)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of Borderline ("*Kouri*") has reposted the majority of his work online [here](http://knkfics.livejournal.com/216148.html).

You can find the original works by "*Kouri and Karsua*" on Wayback Machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20081208094514/http://www.fatalistic.net/knkfics/)

Comment: That Wayback machine page is a mess. +1 for being able to find anything there :D